# change day number in txt-file

Tags: bash, sed

Hi it is my first time that I have a txt-file with daily data looking like:

```
Station Year Month Day Q Deficit Duration SumDeficit SumDuration
3613100 1975 1 1 2.44 -2.233 1 -2.233 1
3613100 1975 1 2 2.11 -1.903 1 -4.136 2
3613100 1975 1 3 1.8 -1.593 1 -5.729 3
3613100 1975 1 4 1.6 -1.393 1 -7.122 4
3613100 1975 1 5 1.48 -1.273 1 -8.395 5
3613100 1975 1 6 1.72 -1.513 1 -9.908 6
3613100 1975 1 7 5.25 -5.043 1 -14.951 7
3613100 1975 1 8 3.44 -3.233 1 -18.184 8
3613100 1975 1 9 2.33 -2.123 1 -20.307 9
3613100 1975 1 10 1.97 -1.763 1 -22.07 10
3613100 1975 1 11 1.7 -1.493 1 -23.563 11
```

Is there a way to change the day specification for the first 9 days of each month from 1 to 01, 2 to 02 ... 9 to 09? And than leaving the other days untouched/unchanged?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
gawk '{ x=sprintf("%02d",$4); sub($4,x,$4); print $0 }' txt-file
```

Comment: Sorry again a short question, as I never used this command before, how can I save these changes in the file? Because it just prints it out in the right way but is not saving it.

Comment: Use `> file_other_then_txt_file` [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections).

Answer (score 1):

I'll just drop by and post a solution without awk:

```
paste -d' ' <(<txt-file cut -d' ' -f-3) <(<txt-file cut -d' ' -f4 | xargs -n1 printf "%02d\n") <(<txt-filecut -d' ' -f5-)
```

The command extracts first 3 column from the file, extracts the 4th column from the file and calls `printf "%02d\n"` on each line, extracts the last columns from the 5th column and then joins the columns on space.

Comment: Thanks! That works too, and thanks for the explanation what everything is doing! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another awk :

```
awk '$4~/^.$/{$4="0"$4}1' infile
```

Or with sed :

```
sed -E 'h;s/([^ ]* ){3}//;/^. /s//0&/;x;s/(([^ ]* ){3}).*/\1/;s/.$//;G;y/\n/ /' infile
```